# Oracle SQL stored procedure cursor is not looping or inserting

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, insert, cursor

I am updating an oracle stored procedure to use a cursor. The purpose is to dynamically insert data from one table to another. The cursor is used to loop and auto increment the field v_SRCROWID which is VARCHAR2 for some reason. I didn't make these tables, so I am just giving my best attempt with my limited use of PL/SQL. I know sequences are usually the way to go, but that's not an option. Within the cursor, I select the max(SRCROWID) and add 1 to it to try to increment the SRCROWID field and I do a dynamic sql statement that inserts into the table. The problem is, it doesn't seem to be looping or inserting anything into the table.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE                                                     

LOOKUP_TABLE_INSERT 
(
P_SOURCE_DB IN VARCHAR2
, P_SOURCE_TABLE IN VARCHAR2
, P_TARGET_DB IN VARCHAR2
, P_TARGET_TABLE IN VARCHAR2
, P_COLUMN_NAME IN VARCHAR2
) AS 
l_sql_statement VARCHAR2(4000);
v_SRCROWID NUMBER(10);

CURSOR c_missingvalues
IS
SELECT MISSING_VALUES AS "PKEY_SRC_OBJECT"
, 1 as "VERSION_SEQ"
, 0 as "TIMELINE_ACTION"
, 1 as "HUB_STATE_IND"
, MISSING_VALUES as "ROLE_TP"
FROM ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.REF_INTERMEDIATE
WHERE COLUMN_NM =  P_COLUMN_NAME --''''||P_COLUMN_NAME||''''
AND LOOKUP_TBL_NM = P_TARGET_TABLE; --''''||P_TARGET_TABLE||'''';

r_missingvalues c_missingvalues%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

v_SRCROWID := 0;
l_sql_statement := '';

OPEN c_missingvalues;
LOOP
SELECT MAX(CAST(SRC_ROWID AS INTEGER)) INTO v_SRCROWID FROM 
ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP;

FETCH c_missingvalues INTO r_missingvalues;
EXIT WHEN c_missingvalues%NOTFOUND;


SELECT 'INSERT INTO '|| P_TARGET_DB ||'.'|| P_TARGET_TABLE||' 
(PKEY_SRC_OBJECT, VERSION_SEQ, TIMELINE_ACTION, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, SRC_ROWID, 
HUB_STATE_IND, ROLE_TP) '||
'VALUES( ' ||''''|| r_missingvalues.PKEY_SRC_OBJECT ||''''|| 
','|| ''''|| r_missingvalues.VERSION_SEQ ||''''||
','|| ''''|| r_missingvalues.TIMELINE_ACTION ||''''|| 
','|| SYSDATE  ||
',' || v_SRCROWID ||' + 1' ||
','|| ''''|| r_missingvalues.HUB_STATE_IND  ||''''|| 
','|| ''''|| r_missingvalues.ROLE_TP ||''''|| 
');' INTO l_sql_statement FROM DUAL;
dbms_output.put_line(l_sql_statement);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_statement;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'COMMIT';


END LOOP;
CLOSE c_missingvalues;
COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: What is the problem with using a sequence?

Comment: Why not use the eazy method   `INTO INTO table (...) SELECT (...) FROM table...` instead iam pretty sure Oracle supports this

Comment: Also be carefull when using stored procedure input directly with a dynamic SQL like this `SELECT 'INSERT INTO '|| P_TARGET_DB ||'.'|| P_TARGET_TABLE||' `  params `P_TARGET_DB`  and `P_TARGET_TABLE` can be used to inject blind SQL injection vectors.. read this https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2

Comment: My workplace does not allow me to use a sequence so I've been trying to do a workaround.

Comment: I am unsure of the eazy method that you are referring to.

Comment: Without sequences you will create inconsistent data in case of multi-user environment if you have uncommited transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dynamic statement is very poor. Better use it like this:

```
l_sql_statement := 'INSERT INTO '|| P_TARGET_DB ||'.'|| P_TARGET_TABLE||' 
  (PKEY_SRC_OBJECT, VERSION_SEQ, TIMELINE_ACTION, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, SRC_ROWID, 
  HUB_STATE_IND, ROLE_TP) 
VALUES 
   (:PKEY_SRC_OBJECT, :VERSION_SEQ, :TIMELINE_ACTION, :LAST_UPDATE_DATE, :SRC_ROWID, 
    :HUB_STATE_IND, :ROLE_TP)';

--dbms_output.put_line(l_sql_statement);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_statement USING 
    r_missingvalues.PKEY_SRC_OBJECT,
    r_missingvalues.VERSION_SEQ,
    r_missingvalues.TIMELINE_ACTION,
    SYSDATE,
    v_SRCROWID + 1, -- or better SEQUENCE_NAME.NEXTVAL,
    r_missingvalues.HUB_STATE_IND,
    r_missingvalues.ROLE_TP;
COMMIT;
```

or even better like this (presuming you cannot use sequences for whatever reason):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOOKUP_TABLE_INSERT (
    P_SOURCE_DB IN VARCHAR2
    , P_SOURCE_TABLE IN VARCHAR2
    , P_TARGET_DB IN VARCHAR2
    , P_TARGET_TABLE IN VARCHAR2
    , P_COLUMN_NAME IN VARCHAR2
    ) AS

    l_sql_statement VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_SRCROWID NUMBER(10);

BEGIN

    SELECT MAX(CAST(SRC_ROWID AS INTEGER)) 
    INTO v_SRCROWID 
    FROM    ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP;

    l_sql_statement := 'INSERT INTO '|| P_TARGET_DB ||'.'|| P_TARGET_TABLE||' 
        (PKEY_SRC_OBJECT, VERSION_SEQ, TIMELINE_ACTION, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, SRC_ROWID, 
        HUB_STATE_IND, ROLE_TP) 
        SELECT MISSING_VALUES, 1, 0, :LAST_UPDATE_DATE, :SRC_ROWID + ROWNUM, 1, MISSING_VALUES ' -- why MISSING_VALUES twice?
        ||' FROM ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.REF_INTERMEDIATE
        WHERE COLUMN_NM =  :P_COLUMN_NAME
        AND LOOKUP_TBL_NM = :P_TARGET_TABLE';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_statement USING SYSDATE, v_SRCROWID, P_COLUMN_NAME, P_TARGET_TABLE;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Hmm, thats actually similar to how I originally had it, but it wouldn't compile so I changed it to how it is. Weird. It's working with what you have though. I do have to say that you are an absolute life saver though. Thank you!

Comment: Just to simplify it slightly more, you could code `sysdate` directly in the statement instead of defining a placeholder and passing in `sysdate` as a bind value.

Comment: That is true, I did that. Thank you again. Is there anyway to increment without using ROWNUM? I'm told this could cause unexpected results later.

Comment: Yes, of course there is a better way - use a SEQUENCE!

Comment: Trust me, if it were up to me, I would use a sequence. I appreciate the help.